# Need help on iptables

Tags: centos, iptables

I have a new server, and am not that sure about iptables. I've tried opening ports (25565, as seen below) but still can't connect. iptables -L says the following;

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:25565
```

I think it's something to do with  reject-with icmp-host-prohibited but I don't really know what that means.

Turning off iptables allows access so it's not the service running that is the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you doing this local or over ssh ? [If you are a newbie with iptables adding removing rules remotely in IPtables could make you lose remote connection].

Answer (score 5):

The rule to accept should be added to the INPUT chain before the one that rejects everything.

The following should work:

```
iptables -I INPUT 4 -p tcp --dport 25565 -j ACCEPT
```

If it worked, then clear your OUTPUT chain and save your iptables settings:

```
iptables -F OUTPUT
/etc/init.d/iptables save
```

Comment: Rule #3 on INPUT is already accepting anything. Could it bethat he needs port forwarding in the router?

Comment: "Turning off iptables allows access so it's not the service running that is the problem.", so it can not be a port forwarding problem.

Answer (score 1):

it should be:

```
iptables -I INPUT 4 -p tcp --dport 25565 --syn -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: That `--syn` is redundant, but the rule is otherwise correct.